# Read boost::asio UDP Broadcast Response

Tags: c++, udp, boost-asio

I am attempting to use boost::asio to implement a simple device discovery protocol.  Basically I want to send a broadcast message (port 9000) with 2 byte payload.  Then read the response from the device (assuming currently it exists).  In wireshark I can see the broadcast is been sent and that the device is responding.  However, in my example code I get that the bytes returned is 0 in the UDP read, not 30 bytes of data.

```
No.  Time      Source         Destination         Protocol  Length
1    0.00000   192.168.0.20   255.255.255.255     UDP       44        52271 -> 9000  Len = 2
2    0.00200   192.168.0.21   192.168.0.20        UDP       72        9000  -> 52271 Len = 30
```

Should I be reading from a different endpoint than broadcastEndpoint?  How do I get the end point?

I am new to asio and trying to teach my self, but I cannot work what I have done wrong.

```
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <iostream>

class udp_find {
public:
    udp_find(boost::asio::io_context& service, unsigned int port)
    : broadcastEndpoint_(boost::asio::ip::address_v4::broadcast(), port),
      socket_(service)
    {
        socket_.open(boost::asio::ip::udp::v4());
        socket_.set_option(boost::asio::ip::udp::socket::reuse_address(true));
        socket_.set_option(boost::asio::socket_base::broadcast(true));

        boost::array<unsigned int, 2> data = {255, 255};
        socket_.async_send_to(
                          boost::asio::buffer(data, 2), broadcastEndpoint_,
                              boost::bind(&udp_find::handle_send, this,
                                          boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                                          boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
}

void handle_receive(const boost::system::error_code& error,
                    std::size_t bytes_transferred)
{
    std::cout << "Received Data" << bytes_transferred << std::endl;
}

void handle_send(const boost::system::error_code& error, std::size_t bytes_transferred)
{
    std::cout << "Sent Data"  << bytes_transferred << std::endl;

    socket_.async_receive_from(
                               boost::asio::buffer(buffer_), broadcastEndpoint_,
                               boost::bind(&udp_find::handle_receive, this,
                                           boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                                               boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    }

private:
    boost::asio::ip::udp::socket socket_;
    boost::array<char, 128> buffer_;
    boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint broadcastEndpoint_;
};

int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_context service;
    udp_find(service, 9000);
    service.run();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first problem is [Udefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You start asynchronous operations on a temporary object of type `udp_find`. The object is destructed immediately after construction, so it doesn't  exist anymore even before you start any of the async work (`service.run()`).

That is easily fixed by making `udp_find` a local variable instead of a temporary:

```
udp_find op(service, 9000);
```

Now sending works for me. You will want to test that receiving works as well. In my `netstat` output it appears that the UDP socket is bound to an ephemeral port. Sending a datagram to that port makes the test succeed for me.

You might want to actually bind/connect to the broadcast address before receiving (the `endpoint&` parameter to `async_receive_from` is *not* for that, I think it is an *output* parameter).

Comment: Sehe - Could you add a little more detail to your last paragraph.  How do I bind to local point with UDP?  I would like to be able in handle_receive log the remote IP address of the sender.